# Scapy - insert packet layer between two other layers

Tags: python, sockets, networking, packet, scapy

I am doing a little networking project using the scapy library for python. My project involves sniffing in packets, and shimming a new layer between layers 3 and 4.

Using this guide, http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/build_dissect.html

I was able to create a new packet layer. I can easily add the layer on top of the existing packet by doing something like,

```
packet = newlayer()/packet
```

And the newlayer() layer will be placed below the IP layer.
I want, however, to sandwich this new layer between layers 3 and 4 (instead of just below IP). But I can't seem to figure out an easy way to accomplish this.

I know that I can just create a new packet and do something like,

```
packet = Ether()/IP()/newlayer()/TCP()
```

however since, I want to insert the layer into packets that I've already sniffed, I'd like to simply modify the original packet instead of creating a new packet from scratch.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29133482/scapy-how-to-insert-a-new-layer-802-1q-into-existing-packet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example that shows how to inject another `Dot1Q()` header between layer 1 and layer 2 (counting `Ether()` as layer 0):

```
>>> pkt = Ether() / Dot1Q() / IP() / TCP()
>>> payload = pkt.getlayer(1).payload
>>> payload
<IP  frag=0 proto=tcp |<TCP  |>>
>>> pkt.getlayer(1).remove_payload()
>>> pkt
<Ether  type=n_802_1Q |<Dot1Q  |>>
>>> newPkt = pkt / Dot1Q() / payload
>>> newPkt
<Ether  type=n_802_1Q |<Dot1Q  type=n_802_1Q |<Dot1Q  type=IPv4 |<IP  frag=0 proto=tcp |<TCP  |>>>>>
>>>
```

There *may* be an easier way, but the above is easy enough I think.